# Get object from array of pointers in parse.com

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I feel silly asking this question but I just cant find the answer and am getting very frustrated. My users have an array column called `"myOrder"` which contains an array of pointers to class `"Order"` . I want to query every single user, call its parseobject from `"Order"` class and sum an integer column called `medicineDiscount`

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser>query1=ParseUser.getQuery();
        query1.setLimit(300);
        query1.include("myOrder");
        query1.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> parseUsers, ParseException e) {

                for (ParseUser user : parseUsers){
                    // get the parseo bjects in "parseOrder" column
                    // Retrieve string from column "discount" for each parse object

                }
            }
        });
```

I tried this

```
for (ParseUser user : parseUsers){
    List<ParseObject> myOrders= user.getList("myOrder");
    Log.d("Orders", " not null");
    for (ParseObject eachOrder : myOrders){
         if (eachOrder.getString("medicineDiscount")!=null && !eachOrder.getString("medicineDiscount").equals("")){
              moneySaved += Float.valueOf(eachOrder.getString("medicineDiscount"));}
{
```

I tried some other variations but kept getting either of these two errors every time

1)     java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseObject
2)     java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.util.List

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: I have a column of type array in `ParseUser` class. it contains `pointers` to another Class called `Order`. The column name is `myOrder`. I want to query the parse objects of Class `Order` that are in the column myOrder (they are in the form of an array of pointers). I have already used query.include.

Comment: did you try like `user.getJSONObject("myOrder")` or `getJSONArray("")`